# Как удалить сердечки и прочие знаки из строки? &#9829

Tags: php

Пытаюсь из строки удалить знаки в виде сердечек и другие, думал, что это emoji но оказалось, что нет.
Знаки имеют вид в коде такой `&#9829`

remove_emoji

html_entity_decode

htmlspecialchars

strip_tags не помогло, как избавиться от этих знаков?

Спасибо!

Мой код для чпу

```
//создаем чпу
function translitURL($str) 
    {
    $tr = array(
        "А"=>"a","Б"=>"b","В"=>"v","Г"=>"g",
        "Д"=>"d","Е"=>"e","Ё"=>"yo","Ж"=>"zh","З"=>"z","И"=>"i",
        "Й"=>"j","К"=>"k","Л"=>"l","М"=>"m","Н"=>"n",
        "О"=>"o","П"=>"p","Р"=>"r","С"=>"s","Т"=>"t",
        "У"=>"u","Ф"=>"f","Х"=>"h","Ц"=>"c","Ч"=>"ch",
        "Ш"=>"sh","Щ"=>"shh","Ъ"=>"j","Ы"=>"i","Ь"=>"",
        "Э"=>"e","Ю"=>"yu","Я"=>"ya","а"=>"a","б"=>"b",
        "в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","е"=>"e","ё"=>"yo","ж"=>"zh",
        "з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"j","к"=>"k","л"=>"l",
        "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
        "с"=>"s","т"=>"t","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h",
        "ц"=>"c","ч"=>"ch","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"shh","ъ"=>"j",
        "ы"=>"i","ь"=>"","э"=>"e","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya", 
        " "=> "-", "."=> "", "І"=> "i",
        "і"=> "i", "Ң"=> "n", "ң"=> "n", 
        "Ү"=> "u", "ү"=> "u", "Қ"=> "q", 
        "қ"=> "q", "Ұ"=> "u",
        "ұ"=> "u", "Ғ"=> "g", "ғ"=> "g", 
        "Ө"=> "o", "ө"=> "o", "Ә"=> "a", 
        "ә"=> "a"                           
    );
    // Убираю тире, дефисы внутри строки
    $urlstr = str_replace('–'," ",$str);
    $urlstr = str_replace('-'," ",$urlstr); 
    $urlstr = str_replace('—'," ",$urlstr);

    // Убираю лишние пробелы внутри строки
    $urlstr=preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$urlstr);
     if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-]/', $urlstr)) {
        $urlstr = strtr($urlstr,$tr);
        $urlstr = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-]/', '', $urlstr);
        $urlstr = strtolower($urlstr);
        return $urlstr;
    } else {
        return strtolower($str);
    }
}
// end чпу
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать что это за символ можно использовать сайт https://unicode-table.com. И это не эмодзи, а символ `Черви закрашенные`. https://unicode-table.com/ru/2665/
Вообще можно сделать замену всех символов, которые не входят в regex разрешённых вами, на их HTML-коды или на unicode-коды. К сожалению, не помню как это делается.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне вообще нужно удалить эти знаки, я создаю чпу урл из заголовка и они мне мешают, пока удалить не получилось.

Comment: @MicroRu если делаете чпу, то вам проще указать белый список символов, а остальное резать.... на мой взгляд так будет проще. То есть сначала из заголовка сделайте латиницу, и потом сравните с белым списком, например через регулярку.

Answer (score 0):

У меня написана такая функция, которая удаляет emodji и подобные символы, попробуйте

```
function remove_emodji($text){
    $char_array = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $text);
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($char_array); $x++) if(strlen($char_array[$x]) > 3) $char_array[$x] = '';
    return implode($char_array, '');
}
```